# How to develop a plugin with subdirectory as dependency in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I came across several plugins with the following structure:

```
my_plugin/
my_plugin_platform_interfance/
my_plugin_web/
README.md
```

Inside the main implementation, the file `my_plugin/pubspec.yaml` depends on both:

```
my_plugin_platform_interface: ^1.0.3
my_plugin_web: ^1.0.10
```

But I need to make change in both `my_plugin_platform_interface` and `my_plugin_web`.

1. I am not sure if this is the correct thing to do (but it feels wrong): I just commented these two lines and replaced with:

Please tell me if there is a proper way than this

```
my_plugin_platform_interface: 
  path: ../my_plugin_platform_interface/
my_plugin_web: 
  path: ../my_plugin_web/
```

2. I finished the change but I am not willing to publish it to dart pub. I just want to use it as a git repo directly.

So in my project I added:

```
my_plugin: 
    git:
      url: git://github.com/TSR/my_plugin.git
      ref: my/branch
      path: my_plugin
```

But now I get the following error:

```
Flutter pub get
Running "flutter pub get" in my_project...            
Error on line 18, column 11: Invalid description in the "my_plugin" pubspec on the "my_plugin_platform_interface" dependency: "../my_plugin_platform_interface/" is a relative path, but this isn't a local pubspec.

   ╷

18 │     path: ../my_plugin_platform_interface/

   │           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

   ╵
pub get failed (65;    ╵)
exit code 65
```

So does this mean I should also edit my plugin dependency to

```
my_plugin_platform_interface: 
    git:
      url: git://github.com/TSR/my_plugin.git
      ref: my/branch
      path: my_plugin_platform_interface

my_plugin_web: 
    git:
      url: git://github.com/TSR/my_plugin.git
      ref: my/branch
      path: my_plugin_web
```

This feels even more wrong. Can someone tell me if there is a proper way to do this